# Google Workspace Marketplace authentication process - Auto created credentials

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

We are trying to publish an Add-on to Google Workspace Marketplace and are getting an error as below:
Our "project" is having too many unauthorized domains that do not belong to us.
After reviewing these, it is google.com and googleapis.com. Both of these are tied to credentials that were auto-created and "required for our project".
These credentials are also tied to permissions and service accounts of the project.
We are looking for some thoughts on if these auto-created permissions, service account, and credentials are needed. Or, if we have our own permissions, service account, and credentials can we just remove all the other Google-related ones.

The question is, does anyone know what Google might be asking about when they say a project is in development or staging? And, do you need to keep the IAM accounts, credentials, and domains to get verified for google OAuth verification? If so, what are they used for?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is, can you please elaborate?